What's the airplane with the smallest ratio of wingspan to fuselage width?
I want to know (preferably within the General Aviation category) which airplane has the smallest wingspan compared to its fuselage width.
(I'm curious of the performance of such an airplane)

If we look beyond GA, the XF-85 goblin (and to a lesser extent other parasite fighters) comes to mind, though I suspect it’s not the smallest ratio produced.

Even though not an airplane in the full concept, the space shuttle is also a candidate.

The "flying bathtub" comes to my mind.  It was only a prototype though.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_M2-F1

I'm curious what the BD-5/BD-5J comes to?

Do helicopters and rockets count? And what about a zeppelin?

I think the Stits SA-2A Sky Baby should be in the running.


wow, never heard of it, looks like a toy.

It's also in the running for prop bigger than wings!

Excluding the cowl bumps, it's about 3.2.

Omg that is so cute

A well-known GA airplane that looks like a blended wing body is the Dyke Delta homebuilt.  Measuring Wikipedia's three-view of the JD-2 variant yields a wingspan to fuselage-width ratio of 3.0 to 3.7, depending on how you argue about fairings.

The similar Wainfan Facetmobile is a lifting body, for an unbeatable ratio of 1.0.  (Conversely, a flying wing's ratio could be said to be infinity.)

Ahhh, yes.  The Facetmobile.  Looks like a paper airplane... Neat!

I was gonna post about lifting bodies but I think this covers that.

@ThomasPerry the Facetmobile's origami, never mind a lack of compound curves, has made it a popular subject for radio-control models.


which airplane has the smallest wingspan compared to its fuselage width?

By definition it would be an airplane where the fuselage is the wing. Such kind of aircraft where extensively flown during the '50s to understand the aerodynamic characteristics of the future re-entry vehicles and are termed lifting body aircrafts:

With a ratio of 1:1 they are formally unbeatable.

Anyway if we restrict our search to GA airplane then, according to the Guinness world record, the Bumblebee Starr II with a wingspan of 1.68m (5 ft 6 in) is the world's smallest piloted airplane. Unfortunately it crashed due to an engine problem and the picture you find around with the plane in yellow-black stripes is the Bumblebee Starr I which was a bit bigger. Anyway this should be it with Starr himself (source):

With a wingspan of 1.91m (6 ft 3 in) the Sits DS-1 Baby Bird is the world's smallest monoplane:

Missing official measures, I'd say that here we are around a ratio of 3:1 I'd guess.

Ratios?  Excluding cowl, or lack thereof.

Wow, is that prop hub bizarre because the two blades are separate?!  ... ah, EAA says "ground adjustable", presumably in pitch, thus separate blades.

Refreshing that you mentioned these examples.  The next question is obvious:  Will it kill you?  A sensible deterrent to the sane person... Excellent examples, tho...

@chux-ReinstateMonica, fuselage width.  I've edited the question's title to clarify.

@CamilleGoudeseune "smallest ratio of wingspan to fuselage width" --> OK, so a width-to-width ratio and not necessarily a small ship?  E.g. the space shuttle ratio of 78/18 or 4.3

thanks @sophit form bringing up the term "lifting body", I had heard it before but didn't recall it, and definitely it was appropriate to bring it up to this post.

And just for comparison, a military aircraft. Not general aviation, tho... Yes, this is the F-104.  Approx. 3.27 +/-.  

On that theme, I was curious how the Phantom scored, being the Triumph Of Thrust Over Aerodynamics. Turns out its wings aren't quite as stubby as a Starfighter though, even though the body is fatter.

@Graham   Answer: - about 4 +/- ...

More than a few of them aren't military.  +1.

I came here to mention the rare GA version of the F1-4 (cough). This link suggests 2.5:1 https://www.britannica.com/technology/F-104.  16.7:6.68

@RussellMcMahon  Yep... they are mentioning fuselage length while the current consideration is fuselage width.  Hence the difference... Oh, and that GA version of the 104... No laxative needed!

You might consider the 1955 Pritchard Rocket Air Ship, (which was neither a rocket nor an airship) with the major caveat that it never actually got off the ground.

source

source

Charles Pritchard, designer builder and pilot, makes first test of his
wingless Rocket Air Ship on mile lone runway at Emporia, Virginia,
airport, 8A-1030A today, (Friday). Plane has short baffles or fins in
place of wings, 90 hp engine, conventional propeller and tail
assembly, tricycle landing gear, is 21 feet long 98 inches wide weighs
800 lbs. Pritchard made eight runs along runway, but didn’t; get off
the ground. Says he’ll make modifications and try again.

The CAA eventually made him stop trying.
Alternatively, for a plane that actually got airborne, there is the Model C Speedbird (N38C or NX38C) by Merle Larson, a former WW2 B-24 pilot who modified a Taylorcraft BC-12. The wingspan is reported as 12' while the fuselage is approximately 4'2" wide, or was before it crashed.


An All-American master craftsman, Merle Larson took things in his
hands when he decided to test a new wing  of his own design design in
1953. Larson took a mundane Taylorcraft BC-12 and replaced its standard wing with this very tiny thing. His wing was designed to work
within the high-speed slipstream of the propeller to generate more
than the normal lift. Then came the time of truth. The “plane” was
doing quite well on its maiden flight, but guess what?, yeah, the
engine suddenly stopped. The Speed Bird went down like a proverbial
brick and crashed trapping Mr. Larson, thankfully unhurt.
source


Yes indeedy, that modified Taylorcraft would glide hardly better than one whose stock wing had fallen off!

Maybe not a winner, but a not-to-be-missed aircraft nonetheless, the Gee Bee Model R Super Sportster

Image source
With a wing span of 7.62 m and a fuselage width of 1.98 m, it ends up with a ratio of 3.85.
